# How to trigger azure devops pipeline CI CD through powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Seeking your assistance in how to trigger azure devops pipeline CI CD using powershell

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few PowerShell modules out there but I don't know a module that provides a cmdlet to trigger a pipeline. However, Azure DevOps has an API including a [Run Pipeline endpoint](http://Runs%20-%20Run%20Pipeline). Before you use it you have to [Choose the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). I usually use a Personal access token (PAT) for authentication in my scripts.